# Many to many relationship not persisted correctly

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

Please see the DDL below:

```
create table Person (ID identity not null, varchar(name), primary key (id))
create table PersonSport (PersonID int not null references Person(ID), SportID int not null references Sport(ID))
create table Sport (ID identity int not null, description varchar(20), primary key(id))
insert into sport (description) values ('running') //ID =1 from auto increment
insert into sport (description) values ('football') //ID = 2 from auto increment
```

Entity Framework correctly creates two classes i.e. Person and Sport.  I then try this:

```
public int Create()
        {
            Person person = new Person();
        person.name = 'Bert';
             List<Sport> listSport = new List<Sport>;

            Sport sport = new Sport();
            sport.ID=1; //ID=1 is running
            Sport.Description='running';
            listSport.Add(sport);
            person.Sport = listSport;

            using (PersonSportEntities db = new PersonSportEntities())
            {
                db.Person.Add(person);
                db.SaveChanges();
            }
        }
```

After this has run; it appears Entity Framework has done this:

1) `INSERT INTO Sport (description) values ('running');` //ID=3 from auto increment

2) INSERT INTO Person (name) values ('Bert')

3) `INSERT INTO PersonSport (1,3); //3 is the auto increment from step 1`

I would expect it just to do this:

1) INSERT INTO Person (name) values ('Bert')

2) `INSERT INTO PersonSport (1,2);`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: what is dbApplications entity type?

Comment: @Ikram Turgunbaev, thanks.  I have updated the question.  That was just a typo.

Comment: @Evk, thanks.  You are correct.  I have edited the question.  How can I ensure EF writes to Person and PersonSport only? Sport is a lookup table in this scenario.

Comment: I suppose you need to tell EF that `sport` is not a new entity, by doing `db.Entry(sport).State = EntityState.Unmodified`. Or fetch sport from database and not create in code (can be undesirable).

Comment: use AddOrUpdate instead of Add

Comment: Something is wrong with your model - there shouldn't be a `Sport` property in `Person`, but collection of `Sport` (many-to-many, right?)

Comment: @Ivan Stoev, thanks.  I have edited the question.

Comment: @Evk, how can I do this in light of Ivan Stoevs' comment?

Comment: I suppose that doesn't change anything related to my comment.

Comment: Before calling `db.Person.Add(person);`, just `Attach` the `Sport` objects (thus telling EF that they are **existing**), e.g. `foreach (var sport in person.Sport) db.Sport.Attach(sport);`

Comment: @Evk, how would I pass a collection of sports to the Entry method? Thanks.

Comment: You don't need to pass a collection - you have just one sport entity. Instead of setting state you can Attach it as Ivan suggests above - I think the end result is the same.

Comment: @Evk, this is a simple example I used to explain the problem.  My actual problem means that multiple sports could be created.

Comment: Then just do this for each of them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Before `Add` the `Person` instance to the context, simply `Attach` the `Sport` instances (thus telling EF to treat them as existing, rather than new as if you don't do that):

```
using (PersonSportEntities db = new PersonSportEntities())
{
    foreach (var sport in person.Sport)
        db.Sport.Attach(sport);
    db.PersonSport.Add(personSport);
    db.SaveChanges();
}
```

In this case you don't need to specify `Sport` objects properties other than `Id` since they are fake (a.k.a. *stub*) objects just to create links.

Comment: Thanks, this does exactly what I would expect.  +1.  I am looking at another application that someone else developed and they do not loop through all the sports to attach them.  EF appears to deal with this implicitly.  Is there a way to configure EF to do this implicitly?

Comment: Unfortunately no. Working with disconnected entities has always been left for the developers using the EF.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way,

```
public int Create()
    {
        Person person = new Person();
        person.name = 'Bert';

        using (PersonSportEntities db = new PersonSportEntities())
        {   
            List<Sport> sport = db.Sport.Where(x => x.ID = 1).ToList();
            person.Sport = sport;

            db.Person.Add(person);
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please would you have another look at the question.  Person.Sport is a list.

Comment: Why did you share not correct/missing codes, is it exactly true code that you are using?

Answer (score -1):

I think you must have 3 models. `Person`, `PersonSport` and `Sport`

```
public class PersonSport
{
   public int Id {get; set;} //key and auto increment
   public int PersonId {get; set} //foreign key
   public int SportId {get; set} // foreign key

// relationship
   public virtual Person Person {get; set;} 
   public virtual Sport Sport {get; set;} 
}

public int Create()
    {
        var personSport=new PersonSport();
        personSport.SportId=1; 
        personSport.Person=new Person()
        {
         Name="Bert"
        };
        using (PersonSportEntities db = new PersonSportEntities())
        {   
            db.PersonSport.Add(personSport);
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Entity Framework does not create a class for PersonSport because it contains a composite primary key only.

Comment: @w0051977 1. Your table structure is wrong. 2.Entity Framework is able create composite primary key table. 3.Your `PersonSport `table must contains composite foreign key